# Как в Tkinter считать текст из виджета Text и построчно выполнить команды в нём

Tags: python, tkinter

Необходимо реализовать такую систему.
Изначально у банка один клиент, на него должен быть открыт счёт с любой суммой.
В отдельном поле должна быть предусмотрена возможность ввода простых команд, которые поддерживают следующие операции:

DEPOSIT name sum Зачислить сумму sum на счет клиента name. Если клиента нет, то он создается и на него заводится счет с указанной суммой.

WITHDRAW name sum Снять сумму sum со счета клиента name. Если клиента, то счет создается. Баланс при выполнении такой операции у вновь созданного клиента должен быть отрицательный.

BALANCE name Узнать остаток средств на счету клиента name. Для каждого запроса BALANCE программа должна вывести остаток на счету данного клиента. Если же у клиента с запрашиваемым именем не открыт счет в банке, выводится сообщение «NO CLIENT». Если пользователь не указал имя клиента – то выводится баланс всех существующих клиентов.

TRANSFER name1 name2 sum Перевести сумму sum со счета клиента name1 на счет клиента name2. Если у какого-либо клиента, то он заводится в системе и ему создается счет с переведенной суммой.

INCOME p Начислить всем клиентам, у которых открыты счета, p% от суммы счета. Проценты начисляются только клиентам с положительным остатком на счету, если у клиента остаток отрицательный, то его счет не меняется. После начисления процентов сумма на счету остается целой, то есть начисляется только целое число денежных единиц. Дробная часть начисленных процентов отбрасывается.

Программа должна обрабатывать желаемые команды, при этом каждая новая команда вводится с новой строки, а потом нажимает на кнопку "Calculate". Результат должен быть выведен в поле справа.
Количество команд, которые может ввести пользователь за один раз – не более 20. При необходимости следует предусмотреть прокрутку в поле. Пользователю допускается вводить "пустые строки" - несколько раз нажимать на кнопку "enter".

```
from tkinter import *
 
win = Tk()
win.geometry('750x750')
win.minsize(width='750', height='750')
win.maxsize(width='750', height='750')
 
 
def clears():
    Texts.delete('1.0',END)
 
 
 
cli = {'test':3000}
 
def start():
    inputs_1 = Texts.get('1.0', END) 
    inputs_2 = inputs_1.split()
 
    comand = inputs_2[0]
    name = inputs_2[1]
    balanse = cli[name]
    sums = int(inputs_2[2])
    for i in inputs_2:
        if i == 'DEPOSIT':
            cli['%s'%name] += sums
            print(cli)
 
 
 
 
 
Texts = Text(win, width='50', height='9', wrap='word', font='arial 20')
Texts.place(x='14', y='450')
 
scr = Scrollbar(command=Texts.yview)
scr.pack(side=RIGHT, fill = Y)
Texts.config(yscrollcommand=scr.set)
 
 
Zapusk = Button(win, width='15', height='5', text='Запуск', font='arial 10', command=start)
Zapusk.place( y='350',x='607')
 
Clear = Button(win, width='15', height='5', text='Очистить', font='arial 10', command=clears)
Clear.place(y='350', x='15')
 
line = Canvas(bg='green', width='750', height='3')
line.place(y='350', x=0)
 
 
 
win.mainloop()
```

Выполняется только 1 команда. Другие не читаются. Не получается прочитать и выполнить всё построчно из виджета Text. Пробовал ставить цикл и очищать 1 значения в списке, эфекта не было.

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Текст, полученный из `Text`, нужно разбить на отдельные строки, потом циклом по этим строкам пройти, каждую строку разбивая по пробелам.

Пример:

```
def start():
    inputs_1 = Texts.get('1.0', END)
    lines = inputs_1.splitlines()  # Разбиваем весь текст на отдельные строки

    # Циклом идем по строкам, каждую строку обрабатываем отдельно
    for line in lines:
        if line:  # Если не пустая строка
            line = line.split()
            command = line[0]
            
            if command == 'DEPOSIT':
                if len(line) < 3:
                    print("Для команды DEPOSIT не указано имя или сумма")
                    break  # Останавливаем цикл
                
                name = line[1]
                sum_ = line[2]
                cli[name] += sum_
                print(cli)
            elif command == 'BALANCE':
                print(cli)
            
            ...
```